# Navegar por un JSON Nodejs

Tags: javascript, json, nodejs

Hola amigos estoy recibiendo este objeto **JSON** y quisiera saber como obtener los elementos del segundo objeto, es decir dentro de Data y como puedo separarlos por variables en **java-script**

```
const x = res.json(y que aquí la recibo no? de la llamada un api)

// weno imagino algo como ...

const y = x[1] //pensando que en el 1 está data

{ object: 'list',
  data: 
   [ { id: 'x',
       object: 'customer',
       account_balance: 0,
       created: 1554180065,
       currency: null,
       default_source: 'x',
       delinquent: false,
       description: null,
       discount: null,
       email: 'x',
       invoice_prefix: '878519EE',
       invoice_settings: [Object],
       livemode: false,
       metadata: {},
       shipping: null,
       sources: [Object],
       subscriptions: [Object],
       tax_info: null,
       tax_info_verification: null },
     { id: 'x',
       object: 'customer',
       account_balance: 0,
       created: 1554178299,
       currency: null,
       default_source: 'x',
       delinquent: false,
       description: null,
       discount: null,
       email: 'x',
       invoice_prefix: 'A3B927C3',
       invoice_settings: [Object],
       livemode: false,
       metadata: {},
       shipping: null,
       sources: [Object],
       subscriptions: [Object],
       tax_info: null,
       tax_info_verification: null },
     { id: 'x',
       object: 'customer',
       account_balance: 0,
       created: 1554178198,
       currency: null,
       default_source: 'x',
       delinquent: false,
       description: null,
       discount: null,
       email: 'x',
       invoice_prefix: '467F3BE9',
       invoice_settings: [Object],
       livemode: false,
       metadata: {},
       shipping: null,
       sources: [Object],
       subscriptions: [Object],
       tax_info: null,
       tax_info_verification: null },
     { id: 'x',
       object: 'customer',
       account_balance: 0,
       created: 1553707190,
       currency: null,
       default_source: null,
       delinquent: false,
       description: 'admin',
       discount: null,
       email: 'x',
       invoice_prefix: 'E405588',
       invoice_settings: [Object],
       livemode: false,
       metadata: {},
       shipping: null,
       sources: [Object],
       subscriptions: [Object],
       tax_info: null,
       tax_info_verification: null } ],
  has_more: false,
  url: '/v1/customers' }
```

Comment: Lo de recorrerlo es trivial, pero ... ¿ Que quieres decir con lo de `separarlos por variables` ? Un mínimo de código para aclarar tus iintenciones sería de agradecer :-)

Comment: separarlos todos los hijos de data

Answer (score 0):

data es un array, con lo que con cualquier forma de recorrer un array, puedes acceder a los hijos, 
una de las formas mas habituales es con un for in o con un foreach.

Cuando dices guardarlo en variables, no te entiendo muy bien.

Pero creo que el problema es que no has trabajado nunca con JSON. 
te pongo tu código para que lo veas un poco mas claro.

```
    const x = res.json(y que aquí la recibo no? de la llamada un api)

        // weno imagino algo como ...
    console.log(x.object) // te muestra por consola, list  

    const y = x.data; // aquí accederías a data.

    for(let i =0; i >  y.length; i++ ){
       const dato_en_data = y[i];
       console.log(dato_en_data.id, dato_en_data.object); // mostraría el id y el object de cada resultado. 
    }
```

Espero haberte ayudado y aclarado un poco como funcionan los JSON o objetos javascript.